# remove from search blocked users mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a search engine and a block users table.
I don't want blocked users to appear on search, so I tried:

```
select c.nome, c.user, c.id from users c
where (c.id not in (select `block` from block where user = '1')) 
and c.user like '%uk%' OR c.nome like '%uk%'
```

block table I have id autoincrement, user (who is blocking), block (who is blocked) and date. So I don't want to get results on search from users that user '1' has blocked.

The problem is, it is not working, it is getting blocked users too.

Comment: not in select id from users where block = 1

Comment: @Andrew if I remove `OR c.nome like '%uk%'` it works. but I need to get search based on name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`. Also you confused block and user in your subquery.

```
select nome, id
from users
where id not in (select blocked_user from block where blocking_user = 1)
and (user like '%uk%' OR nome like '%uk%');
```